# How do you QA a Facebook App Install ad that also includes tracking?

Tags: facebook, ads, metrics

We're hoping to run Facebook app install ads for our app and have also set up Facebook's SDK on the backend in order to track the number of installs the ad has garnered. We've done three test runs and so far the stats don't show a single download (there are clicks though). We do not want to run further ads until we're sure we've got the tracking code for installs down pat. Is there an alternative way to test this?

Thanks in advance!